# How to open dolphin with an argument

Tags: 20.04, dolphin

Currently I open the dolphin file viewer with keyboard shortcut `ctrl` + `super` + `home` which runs this command `dolphin -stylesheet dolphin/stylesheet.qss` I want it so that when I manually click it from my desktop/dash it should also open with `dolphin -stylesheet dolphin/stylesheet.qss` rather than just `dolphin`.